# How can i read fist and second column from a tab saparated csv flow file in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have an attribute in a flow file in apachi nifi with tab as delimeter between the values, now in my updateAttribute processor i want to read the first and second column values,below is the example
attribute1 = Hi Hello there.
in my updateattribute processor i have read attribute values as like below
updateAttribute1 = Hi
updateAttribute2=Hello
updateAttribute3 there.
Could any one please help me the the nifi configurations for my updateAttribute processor

Answer (score 0):

@Amarnatha Reddy

Trying to parse an existing attribute is possible with Nifi Expression Language like:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#getdelimitedfield

You could also take a look further upstream where the data arrives into attribute and use a RecordReader based processor to query the data and get the values you want with a bit more flexibility.